# How to trace system calls of a program in Mac OS X?

Tags: macos, strace, truss, dtruss

I wanted to trace the system calls made by the **find** command [to debug some performance issues](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31045501/how-to-speed-up-find-for-listing-git-repositories) however I could not figure out how to do this on Mac OS X Yosemite.  How can I trace system calls for an arbitrary program similarly to what **strace** does on FreeBSD?  I am especially interested in tracing file-system related calls.

---

Suggested [accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46799054/1601580) doesn't work for me. This is what I tried:

```
cd ~
cp /usr/bin/find find
codesign --remove-signature ./find
sudo dtruss ./find …
```

error:

```
codesign --remove-signature ./find
sudo dtruss ./find 
dtrace: system integrity protection is on, some features will not be available

dtrace: failed to execute ./find: Could not create symbolicator for task
```

Comment: A quick search for *strace osx*  gave me [this four year old blog post](https://opensourcehacker.com/2011/12/02/osx-strace-equivalent-dtruss-seeing-inside-applications-what-they-do-and-why-they-hang/). It should be easy to find other alternatives using the same search.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg Nice point. I went another way, starting with *apropos trace* and searching from that. I overlooked *dtruss* and *dtrace* because all outcomes I have found were about a trace utility for the *D* language.

Comment: Just a note, FreeBSD ships with [truss(1)](https://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=truss&manpath=FreeBSD+12.2-RELEASE+and+Ports), not strace.

Comment: did you try the `strace` provided by `brew`? e.g. https://formulae.brew.sh/formula/strace

Comment: @CharlieParker it only supports Linux, not macOS (some people use `brew` on Linux).

Answer (score 85, accepted):

You can use **dtruss** like in

```
sudo dtruss find ~/repo -depth 2 -type d -name '.git'
```

The [manual page](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man1/dtruss.1m.html) of that utility will help you to tailor the use of the tool to your needs.

Comment: dtruss did work then (June '15) but was broken by the System Integrity Protection regime of El Capitan.

Comment: @Olsonist Same issue with dtrace: `the current security restriction (rootless enabled) prevent dtrace from attaching to an executable not signed with the [com.apple.security.get-task-allow] entitlement`

Comment: It is possible to disable SIP https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Security/Conceptual/System_Integrity_Protection_Guide/ConfiguringSystemIntegrityProtection/ConfiguringSystemIntegrityProtection.html

Comment: Also see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33476432/is-there-a-workaround-for-dtrace-cannot-control-executables-signed-with-restri

Comment: Adding a real example is helpful for testing, thanks.

Comment: curious, is there something wrong with using the `strace` provided by `brew`? e.g. https://formulae.brew.sh/formula/strace

Comment: @CharlieParker strace is only available for Linux.

Comment: this answer fails:
```

dtrace: system integrity protection is on, some features will not be available

dtrace: failed to execute find: Operation not permitted
```

Answer (score 111):

Under current versions of macOS, executables under paths covered by SIP (like `/usr/bin`) cannot be traced.

You can bypass this by making a copy of the executable in your home directory and tracing the copy:

```
cp /usr/bin/find find
codesign --remove-signature ./find
sudo dtruss ./find …
```

You needed to remove the code signature from the new `find` executable, otherwise SIP still notices that a system file is being accessed (credit: @Anmol Singh Jaggi).

Comment: In my case after copying of the executable the bug that I wanted to debug stopped happening ..(

Comment: Probably my bug is really SIP-related so that's a success too.

Comment: Not working on macOS 10.15.4.
Had to execute `codesign --remove-signature ./find` first.

Comment: MacOs does not executes the program after its signature is removed. I get error something like this `cannot open this program, source is untrusted`

Comment: @CharlieParker Homebrew also works on Linux. :) strace is for Linux.

Comment: Does not work for me on MacOS Monterey with `ls`:
`dtrace: system integrity protection is on, some features will not be available
dtrace: failed to execute ./ls: Could not create symbolicator for task
`

Comment: does work for me, I get this error:
```
dtrace: failed to execute ./find: Could not create symbolicator for task
```

Answer (score 11):

You might have better luck with `ktrace`. For example (on Sonoma 14.0):

```bash
sudo ktrace trace -S -f C3 -c find .
```

`-f` = filter description, `C3` = class 3 = [`DBG_FSYSTEM`](https://github.com/apple-oss-distributions/xnu/blob/aca3bea/bsd/sys/kdebug.h#L99), `-S` = print arguments as strings where possible.

On Yosemite it would have been something like `sudo ktrace -t cin -c find .`

More `ktrace` filter examples in https://stackoverflow.com/a/76987655.

Comment: This is working also in Ventura. The accepted answer it won't work anymore because of the system integrity protection.