# How can I found out what system calls are used for system_profiler SPHardwareDataType

Tags: macos, command-line-arguments, system-calls

I am looking to find out what system calls (at least a one or two, not all of them obviously) are being used when using the following command in Mac OSX 10.11.3

system_profiler SPHardwareDataType

I'm just not sure how to find out about the system calls in relation to the command.

Thanks,
Jo

Comment: Have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31045575/how-to-trace-system-calls-of-a-program-in-mac-os-x

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the [reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31045575/how-to-trace-system-calls-of-a-program-in-mac-os-x) I gave in my earlier comment:

```
sudo dtruss system_profiler
```

`dtruss` runs your command and traces the system calls.

`sudo` runs the dtruss command with root priviledge (you need to be member of the `sudoer` group; may require you to enter your password).

You may pipe the output through `grep` to filter the output:

```
sudo dtruss system_profiler | grep <phrase you are looking for>
```

You can find detailed info on all these commands using:

```
man <cmd>
```

You can search the man pages for keywords:

```
man -k <keyword>
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I appreciate it.  When I try the sudo dtruss system_profiler and enter my password I get the following:  dtrace: failed to execute system_profiler: dtrace cannot control executables signed with restricted entitlements...any ideas on that one?  Thanks a ton.

Comment: @Jo-Anne B: I'm not a Mac User, but http://internals.exposed/blog/dtrace-vs-sip.html shows a way to disable System Integrity Protection, which is the OS feature, that causes dtruss to fail ...