# OSX cannot close server ports properly

Tags: bash, macos, server

I use local server enviroments on my mac. But every time I close the server by terminal process is still working so when I want to turn it on again I've got error that port I used previously is already occupied. So I need to find and kill that process with

```
netstat -vanp tcp | grep [PORT]
```

command which is very annoing and time-wasting. This is not related to any server technology since I've got the same problem using both Node.js and Ruby on Rails. It's something wrong with OSX. How can I fix that issue? I use OSX El Capitain version 10.11.6

Comment: You could try trace the command used to "close the server" with `dtruss`

Comment: I simply type CMD + C to stop the server. It works fine on my second mac computer

Comment: CMD + C sends a kill signal to the server PID, to debug precede the kill command with dtruss, see: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31045575/how-to-trace-system-calls-of-a-program-in-mac-os-x

Comment: CMD+C performs a clipboard-copy on MacOS. Did you mean to type Ctrl+C?