# Why does the imap.so PHP extension make network calls when I bootstrap PHP?

Tags: php, command-line-interface, php-extension

I noticed that sometimes, when I lose Internet connection and I try to run PHP interactively from the command line:

```
$ php -a
```

It hangs. I really have to wait several seconds before seeing the interactive prompt:

```
$ php -a
Interactive shell

php >
```

After investigating and changing different configuration values of the `php.ini` used by the command line command, I found out that the problem was the IMAP extension:

```
; within the php.ini loaded by the php CLI command
; ...

extension=imap.so

; ...
```

If, while not having lost Internet connection, I comment that line:

```
; within the php.ini loaded by the php CLI command
; ...

;extension=imap.so ; <--- Comment it

; ...
```

And run `php -a` from the CLI, I can instantly see the interactive prompt:

```
$ php -a
Interactive shell

php >
```

My guess is that the `imap.so` extension is making a network call when I bootstrap PHP and when I lose Internet connection, it hangs before reaching a time out of several seconds and showing me the prompt.

Why does `imap.so` behave like this?

Thank you for your attention.

**EDIT:**

I retried to run `$ sudo dtruss php -a` several times, here is what it shows while it hangs (before seeing `Interactive sheel` from the bottom, I have omitted the higher lines because the output would exceed 30000 characters otherwise):

```
$ sudo dtruss php -a
... <--- OMITTED SOME OUTPUT HERE
getattrlist("/Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php7.2.14/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20170718\0", 0x108AAD088, 0x7FFEEDEBFD70)      = 0 0
getattrlist("/Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php7.2.14/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20170718/gettext.so\0", 0x108AAD088, 0x7FFEEDEBFD70)       = 0 0
stat64("/Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php7.2.14/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20170718/gettext.so\0", 0x7FFEEDEC0630, 0x0)        = 0 0
open("/Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php7.2.14/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20170718/gettext.so\0", 0x0, 0x0)         = 3 0
pread(0x3, "\317\372\355\376\a\0", 0x1000, 0x0)      = 4096 0
mmap(0x1037DE000, 0x3000, 0x5, 0x12, 0x3, 0x0)       = 0x1037DE000 0
mmap(0x1037E1000, 0x1000, 0x3, 0x12, 0x3, 0x3000)        = 0x1037E1000 0
mmap(0x1037E2000, 0xC2C, 0x1, 0x12, 0x3, 0x4000)         = 0x1037E2000 0
close(0x3)       = 0 0
getattrlist("/Applications\0", 0x108AAD088, 0x7FFEEDEBFB70)      = 0 0
getattrlist("/Applications/MAMP\0", 0x108AAD088, 0x7FFEEDEBFB70)         = 0 0
getattrlist("/Applications/MAMP/Library\0", 0x108AAD088, 0x7FFEEDEBFB70)         = 0 0
getattrlist("/Applications/MAMP/Library/lib\0", 0x108AAD088, 0x7FFEEDEBFB70)         = 0 0
getattrlist("/Applications/MAMP/Library/lib/libintl.8.dylib\0", 0x108AAD088, 0x7FFEEDEBFB70)         = 0 0
stat64("/Applications/MAMP/Library/lib/libintl.8.dylib\0", 0x7FFEEDEC0430, 0x0)      = 0 0
open("/Applications/MAMP/Library/lib/libintl.8.dylib\0", 0x0, 0x0)       = 3 0
pread(0x3, "\317\372\355\376\a\0", 0x1000, 0x0)      = 4096 0
mmap(0x105959000, 0xF000, 0x5, 0x12, 0x3, 0x0)       = 0x105959000 0
mmap(0x105968000, 0x1000, 0x3, 0x12, 0x3, 0xF000)        = 0x105968000 0
mmap(0x105969000, 0x2900, 0x1, 0x12, 0x3, 0x10000)       = 0x105969000 0
close(0x3)       = 0 0
getattrlist("/Applications\0", 0x108AAD088, 0x7FFEEDEBFD70)      = 0 0
getattrlist("/Applications/MAMP\0", 0x108AAD088, 0x7FFEEDEBFD70)         = 0 0
getattrlist("/Applications/MAMP/bin\0", 0x108AAD088, 0x7FFEEDEBFD70)         = 0 0
getattrlist("/Applications/MAMP/bin/php\0", 0x108AAD088, 0x7FFEEDEBFD70)         = 0 0
getattrlist("/Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php7.2.14\0", 0x108AAD088, 0x7FFEEDEBFD70)       = 0 0
getattrlist("/Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php7.2.14/lib\0", 0x108AAD088, 0x7FFEEDEBFD70)       = 0 0
getattrlist("/Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php7.2.14/lib/php\0", 0x108AAD088, 0x7FFEEDEBFD70)       = 0 0
getattrlist("/Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php7.2.14/lib/php/extensions\0", 0x108AAD088, 0x7FFEEDEBFD70)        = 0 0
getattrlist("/Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php7.2.14/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20170718\0", 0x108AAD088, 0x7FFEEDEBFD70)      = 0 0
getattrlist("/Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php7.2.14/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20170718/pgsql.so\0", 0x108AAD088, 0x7FFEEDEBFD70)         = 0 0
stat64("/Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php7.2.14/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20170718/pgsql.so\0", 0x7FFEEDEC0630, 0x0)      = 0 0
open("/Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php7.2.14/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20170718/pgsql.so\0", 0x0, 0x0)       = 3 0
pread(0x3, "\317\372\355\376\a\0", 0x1000, 0x0)      = 4096 0
mmap(0x10596C000, 0x28000, 0x5, 0x12, 0x3, 0x0)      = 0x10596C000 0
mmap(0x105994000, 0x4000, 0x3, 0x12, 0x3, 0x28000)       = 0x105994000 0
mmap(0x105998000, 0x57E0, 0x1, 0x12, 0x3, 0x2C000)       = 0x105998000 0
close(0x3)       = 0 0
getattrlist("/Applications\0", 0x108AAD088, 0x7FFEEDEBFB90)      = 0 0
getattrlist("/Applications/MAMP\0", 0x108AAD088, 0x7FFEEDEBFB90)         = 0 0
getattrlist("/Applications/MAMP/Library\0", 0x108AAD088, 0x7FFEEDEBFB90)         = 0 0
getattrlist("/Applications/MAMP/Library/pg\0", 0x108AAD088, 0x7FFEEDEBFB90)      = 0 0
getattrlist("/Applications/MAMP/Library/pg/lib\0", 0x108AAD088, 0x7FFEEDEBFB90)      = 0 0
getattrlist("/Applications/MAMP/Library/pg/lib/libpq.5.dylib\0", 0x108AAD088, 0x7FFEEDEBFB90)        = 0 0
readlink("/Applications/MAMP/Library/pg/lib/libpq.5.dylib\0", 0x7FFEEDEBEF90, 0x400)         = 15 0
getattrlist("/Applications/MAMP/Library/pg/lib/libpq.5.2.dylib\0", 0x108AAD088, 0x7FFEEDEBFB90)      = -1 Err#2
stat64("/Applications/MAMP/Library/pg/lib/libpq.5.dylib\0", 0x7FFEEDEC0450, 0x0)         = -1 Err#2
getattrlist("/Users\0", 0x108AAD088, 0x7FFEEDEBFF60)         = 0 0
getattrlist("/Users/antony\0", 0x108AAD088, 0x7FFEEDEBFF60)      = 0 0
getattrlist("/Users/antony/lib\0", 0x108AAD088, 0x7FFEEDEBFF60)      = -1 Err#2
stat64("/Users/antony/lib/libpq.5.dylib\0", 0x7FFEEDEC0820, 0x0)         = -1 Err#2
getattrlist("/Users\0", 0x108AAD088, 0x7FFEEDEC00F0)         = 0 0
getattrlist("/Users/antony\0", 0x108AAD088, 0x7FFEEDEC00F0)      = 0 0
getattrlist("/Users/antony/lib\0", 0x108AAD088, 0x7FFEEDEC00F0)      = -1 Err#2
getattrlist("/Users\0", 0x108AAD088, 0x7FFEEDEBFB30)         = 0 0
getattrlist("/Users/antony\0", 0x108AAD088, 0x7FFEEDEBFB30)      = 0 0
getattrlist("/Users/antony/lib\0", 0x108AAD088, 0x7FFEEDEBFB30)      = -1 Err#2
stat64("/Users/antony/lib\0", 0x7FFEEDEC03F0, 0x0)       = -1 Err#2
getattrlist("/usr\0", 0x108AAD088, 0x7FFEEDEBFF60)       = 0 0
getattrlist("/usr/local\0", 0x108AAD088, 0x7FFEEDEBFF60)         = 0 0
getattrlist("/usr/local/lib\0", 0x108AAD088, 0x7FFEEDEBFF60)         = 0 0
getattrlist("/usr/local/lib/libpq.5.dylib\0", 0x108AAD088, 0x7FFEEDEBFF60)       = 0 0
readlink("/usr/local/lib/libpq.5.dylib\0", 0x7FFEEDEBF360, 0x400)        = 43 0
getattrlist("/usr/local/Cellar\0", 0x108AAD088, 0x7FFEEDEBFF60)      = 0 0
getattrlist("/usr/local/Cellar/postgresql\0", 0x108AAD088, 0x7FFEEDEBFF60)       = 0 0
getattrlist("/usr/local/Cellar/postgresql/10.3\0", 0x108AAD088, 0x7FFEEDEBFF60)      = 0 0
getattrlist("/usr/local/Cellar/postgresql/10.3/lib\0", 0x108AAD088, 0x7FFEEDEBFF60)      = 0 0
getattrlist("/usr/local/Cellar/postgresql/10.3/lib/libpq.5.dylib\0", 0x108AAD088, 0x7FFEEDEBFF60)        = 0 0
readlink("/usr/local/Cellar/postgresql/10.3/lib/libpq.5.dylib\0", 0x7FFEEDEBF360, 0x400)         = 16 0
getattrlist("/usr/local/Cellar/postgresql/10.3/lib/libpq.5.10.dylib\0", 0x108AAD088, 0x7FFEEDEBFF60)         = 0 0
stat64("/usr/local/lib/libpq.5.dylib\0", 0x7FFEEDEC0820, 0x0)        = 0 0
open("/usr/local/lib/libpq.5.dylib\0", 0x0, 0x0)         = 3 0
pread(0x3, "\317\372\355\376\a\0", 0x1000, 0x0)      = 4096 0
mmap(0x10599E000, 0x34000, 0x5, 0x12, 0x3, 0x0)      = 0x10599E000 0
mmap(0x1059D2000, 0x3000, 0x3, 0x12, 0x3, 0x34000)       = 0x1059D2000 0
mmap(0x1059D5000, 0x7850, 0x1, 0x12, 0x3, 0x37000)       = 0x1059D5000 0
close(0x3)       = 0 0
getattrlist("/usr\0", 0x108AAD088, 0x7FFEEDEBFA50)       = 0 0
getattrlist("/usr/local\0", 0x108AAD088, 0x7FFEEDEBFA50)         = 0 0
getattrlist("/usr/local/opt\0", 0x108AAD088, 0x7FFEEDEBFA50)         = 0 0
getattrlist("/usr/local/opt/openssl\0", 0x108AAD088, 0x7FFEEDEBFA50)         = 0 0
readlink("/usr/local/opt/openssl\0", 0x7FFEEDEBEE50, 0x400)      = 26 0
getattrlist("/usr/local/Cellar\0", 0x108AAD088, 0x7FFEEDEBFA50)      = 0 0
getattrlist("/usr/local/Cellar/openssl\0", 0x108AAD088, 0x7FFEEDEBFA50)      = 0 0
getattrlist("/usr/local/Cellar/openssl/1.0.2o_2\0", 0x108AAD088, 0x7FFEEDEBFA50)         = 0 0
getattrlist("/usr/local/Cellar/openssl/1.0.2o_2/lib\0", 0x108AAD088, 0x7FFEEDEBFA50)         = 0 0
getattrlist("/usr/local/Cellar/openssl/1.0.2o_2/lib/libssl.1.0.0.dylib\0", 0x108AAD088, 0x7FFEEDEBFA50)      = 0 0
stat64("/usr/local/opt/openssl/lib/libssl.1.0.0.dylib\0", 0x7FFEEDEC0310, 0x0)       = 0 0
open("/usr/local/opt/openssl/lib/libssl.1.0.0.dylib\0", 0x0, 0x0)        = 3 0
pread(0x3, "\317\372\355\376\a\0", 0x1000, 0x0)      = 4096 0
mmap(0x105D1D000, 0x40000, 0x5, 0x12, 0x3, 0x0)      = 0x105D1D000 0
mmap(0x105D5D000, 0xA000, 0x3, 0x12, 0x3, 0x40000)       = 0x105D5D000 0
mmap(0x105D68000, 0x12068, 0x1, 0x12, 0x3, 0x4A000)      = 0x105D68000 0
close(0x3)       = 0 0
getattrlist("/usr\0", 0x108AAD088, 0x7FFEEDEBFA50)       = 0 0
getattrlist("/usr/local\0", 0x108AAD088, 0x7FFEEDEBFA50)         = 0 0
getattrlist("/usr/local/opt\0", 0x108AAD088, 0x7FFEEDEBFA50)         = 0 0
getattrlist("/usr/local/opt/openssl\0", 0x108AAD088, 0x7FFEEDEBFA50)         = 0 0
readlink("/usr/local/opt/openssl\0", 0x7FFEEDEBEE50, 0x400)      = 26 0
getattrlist("/usr/local/Cellar\0", 0x108AAD088, 0x7FFEEDEBFA50)      = 0 0
getattrlist("/usr/local/Cellar/openssl\0", 0x108AAD088, 0x7FFEEDEBFA50)      = 0 0
getattrlist("/usr/local/Cellar/openssl/1.0.2o_2\0", 0x108AAD088, 0x7FFEEDEBFA50)         = 0 0
getattrlist("/usr/local/Cellar/openssl/1.0.2o_2/lib\0", 0x108AAD088, 0x7FFEEDEBFA50)         = 0 0
getattrlist("/usr/local/Cellar/openssl/1.0.2o_2/lib/libcrypto.1.0.0.dylib\0", 0x108AAD088, 0x7FFEEDEBFA50)       = 0 0
stat64("/usr/local/opt/openssl/lib/libcrypto.1.0.0.dylib\0", 0x7FFEEDEC0310, 0x0)        = 0 0
open("/usr/local/opt/openssl/lib/libcrypto.1.0.0.dylib\0", 0x0, 0x0)         = 3 0
pread(0x3, "\317\372\355\376\a\0", 0x1000, 0x0)      = 4096 0
mmap(0x105D7B000, 0x170000, 0x5, 0x12, 0x3, 0x0)         = 0x105D7B000 0
mmap(0x105EEB000, 0x25000, 0x3, 0x12, 0x3, 0x170000)         = 0x105EEB000 0
mmap(0x105F13000, 0x500F0, 0x1, 0x12, 0x3, 0x195000)         = 0x105F13000 0
madvise(0x105F13000, 0x2000, 0x2)        = 0 0
close(0x3)       = 0 0
getattrlist("/usr\0", 0x108AAD088, 0x7FFEEDEBF960)       = 0 0
getattrlist("/usr/local\0", 0x108AAD088, 0x7FFEEDEBF960)         = 0 0
getattrlist("/usr/local/Cellar\0", 0x108AAD088, 0x7FFEEDEBF960)      = 0 0
getattrlist("/usr/local/Cellar/openssl\0", 0x108AAD088, 0x7FFEEDEBF960)      = 0 0
getattrlist("/usr/local/Cellar/openssl/1.0.2o_2\0", 0x108AAD088, 0x7FFEEDEBF960)         = 0 0
getattrlist("/usr/local/Cellar/openssl/1.0.2o_2/lib\0", 0x108AAD088, 0x7FFEEDEBF960)         = 0 0
getattrlist("/usr/local/Cellar/openssl/1.0.2o_2/lib/libcrypto.1.0.0.dylib\0", 0x108AAD088, 0x7FFEEDEBF960)       = 0 0
stat64("/usr/local/Cellar/openssl/1.0.2o_2/lib/libcrypto.1.0.0.dylib\0", 0x7FFEEDEC0220, 0x0)        = 0 0
madvise(0x105F13000, 0x2000, 0x5)        = 0 0
getattrlist("/Applications\0", 0x108AAD088, 0x7FFEEDEBFD70)      = 0 0
getattrlist("/Applications/MAMP\0", 0x108AAD088, 0x7FFEEDEBFD70)         = 0 0
getattrlist("/Applications/MAMP/bin\0", 0x108AAD088, 0x7FFEEDEBFD70)         = 0 0
getattrlist("/Applications/MAMP/bin/php\0", 0x108AAD088, 0x7FFEEDEBFD70)         = 0 0
getattrlist("/Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php7.2.14\0", 0x108AAD088, 0x7FFEEDEBFD70)       = 0 0
getattrlist("/Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php7.2.14/lib\0", 0x108AAD088, 0x7FFEEDEBFD70)       = 0 0
getattrlist("/Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php7.2.14/lib/php\0", 0x108AAD088, 0x7FFEEDEBFD70)       = 0 0
getattrlist("/Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php7.2.14/lib/php/extensions\0", 0x108AAD088, 0x7FFEEDEBFD70)        = 0 0
getattrlist("/Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php7.2.14/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20170718\0", 0x108AAD088, 0x7FFEEDEBFD70)      = 0 0
getattrlist("/Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php7.2.14/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20170718/pdo_pgsql.so\0", 0x108AAD088, 0x7FFEEDEBFD70)         = 0 0
stat64("/Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php7.2.14/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20170718/pdo_pgsql.so\0", 0x7FFEEDEC0630, 0x0)      = 0 0
open("/Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php7.2.14/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20170718/pdo_pgsql.so\0", 0x0, 0x0)       = 3 0
pread(0x3, "\317\372\355\376\a\0", 0x1000, 0x0)      = 4096 0
mmap(0x1059DD000, 0xB000, 0x5, 0x12, 0x3, 0x0)       = 0x1059DD000 0
mmap(0x1059E8000, 0x1000, 0x3, 0x12, 0x3, 0xB000)        = 0x1059E8000 0
mmap(0x1059E9000, 0x2680, 0x1, 0x12, 0x3, 0xC000)        = 0x1059E9000 0
close(0x3)       = 0 0
getattrlist("/Applications\0", 0x108AAD088, 0x7FFEEDEBFB90)      = 0 0
getattrlist("/Applications/MAMP\0", 0x108AAD088, 0x7FFEEDEBFB90)         = 0 0
getattrlist("/Applications/MAMP/Library\0", 0x108AAD088, 0x7FFEEDEBFB90)         = 0 0
getattrlist("/Applications/MAMP/Library/pg\0", 0x108AAD088, 0x7FFEEDEBFB90)      = 0 0
getattrlist("/Applications/MAMP/Library/pg/lib\0", 0x108AAD088, 0x7FFEEDEBFB90)      = 0 0
getattrlist("/Applications/MAMP/Library/pg/lib/libpq.5.dylib\0", 0x108AAD088, 0x7FFEEDEBFB90)        = 0 0
readlink("/Applications/MAMP/Library/pg/lib/libpq.5.dylib\0", 0x7FFEEDEBEF90, 0x400)         = 15 0
getattrlist("/Applications/MAMP/Library/pg/lib/libpq.5.2.dylib\0", 0x108AAD088, 0x7FFEEDEBFB90)      = -1 Err#2
stat64("/Applications/MAMP/Library/pg/lib/libpq.5.dylib\0", 0x7FFEEDEC0450, 0x0)         = -1 Err#2
getattrlist("/Users\0", 0x108AAD088, 0x7FFEEDEBFF60)         = 0 0
getattrlist("/Users/antony\0", 0x108AAD088, 0x7FFEEDEBFF60)      = 0 0
getattrlist("/Users/antony/lib\0", 0x108AAD088, 0x7FFEEDEBFF60)      = -1 Err#2
stat64("/Users/antony/lib/libpq.5.dylib\0", 0x7FFEEDEC0820, 0x0)         = -1 Err#2
getattrlist("/Users\0", 0x108AAD088, 0x7FFEEDEC00F0)         = 0 0
getattrlist("/Users/antony\0", 0x108AAD088, 0x7FFEEDEC00F0)      = 0 0
getattrlist("/Users/antony/lib\0", 0x108AAD088, 0x7FFEEDEC00F0)      = -1 Err#2
getattrlist("/Users\0", 0x108AAD088, 0x7FFEEDEBFB30)         = 0 0
getattrlist("/Users/antony\0", 0x108AAD088, 0x7FFEEDEBFB30)      = 0 0
getattrlist("/Users/antony/lib\0", 0x108AAD088, 0x7FFEEDEBFB30)      = -1 Err#2
stat64("/Users/antony/lib\0", 0x7FFEEDEC03F0, 0x0)       = -1 Err#2
getattrlist("/usr\0", 0x108AAD088, 0x7FFEEDEBFF60)       = 0 0
getattrlist("/usr/local\0", 0x108AAD088, 0x7FFEEDEBFF60)         = 0 0
getattrlist("/usr/local/lib\0", 0x108AAD088, 0x7FFEEDEBFF60)         = 0 0
getattrlist("/usr/local/lib/libpq.5.dylib\0", 0x108AAD088, 0x7FFEEDEBFF60)       = 0 0
readlink("/usr/local/lib/libpq.5.dylib\0", 0x7FFEEDEBF360, 0x400)        = 43 0
getattrlist("/usr/local/Cellar\0", 0x108AAD088, 0x7FFEEDEBFF60)      = 0 0
getattrlist("/usr/local/Cellar/postgresql\0", 0x108AAD088, 0x7FFEEDEBFF60)       = 0 0
getattrlist("/usr/local/Cellar/postgresql/10.3\0", 0x108AAD088, 0x7FFEEDEBFF60)      = 0 0
getattrlist("/usr/local/Cellar/postgresql/10.3/lib\0", 0x108AAD088, 0x7FFEEDEBFF60)      = 0 0
getattrlist("/usr/local/Cellar/postgresql/10.3/lib/libpq.5.dylib\0", 0x108AAD088, 0x7FFEEDEBFF60)        = 0 0
readlink("/usr/local/Cellar/postgresql/10.3/lib/libpq.5.dylib\0", 0x7FFEEDEBF360, 0x400)         = 16 0
getattrlist("/usr/local/Cellar/postgresql/10.3/lib/libpq.5.10.dylib\0", 0x108AAD088, 0x7FFEEDEBFF60)         = 0 0
stat64("/usr/local/lib/libpq.5.dylib\0", 0x7FFEEDEC0820, 0x0)        = 0 0
getattrlist("/Applications\0", 0x108AAD088, 0x7FFEEDEBFD70)      = 0 0
getattrlist("/Applications/MAMP\0", 0x108AAD088, 0x7FFEEDEBFD70)         = 0 0
getattrlist("/Applications/MAMP/bin\0", 0x108AAD088, 0x7FFEEDEBFD70)         = 0 0
getattrlist("/Applications/MAMP/bin/php\0", 0x108AAD088, 0x7FFEEDEBFD70)         = 0 0
getattrlist("/Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php7.2.14\0", 0x108AAD088, 0x7FFEEDEBFD70)       = 0 0
getattrlist("/Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php7.2.14/lib\0", 0x108AAD088, 0x7FFEEDEBFD70)       = 0 0
getattrlist("/Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php7.2.14/lib/php\0", 0x108AAD088, 0x7FFEEDEBFD70)       = 0 0
getattrlist("/Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php7.2.14/lib/php/extensions\0", 0x108AAD088, 0x7FFEEDEBFD70)        = 0 0
getattrlist("/Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php7.2.14/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20170718\0", 0x108AAD088, 0x7FFEEDEBFD70)      = 0 0
getattrlist("/Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php7.2.14/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20170718/imagick.so\0", 0x108AAD088, 0x7FFEEDEBFD70)       = 0 0
stat64("/Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php7.2.14/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20170718/imagick.so\0", 0x7FFEEDEC0630, 0x0)        = 0 0
open("/Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php7.2.14/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20170718/imagick.so\0", 0x0, 0x0)         = 3 0
pread(0x3, "\317\372\355\376\a\0", 0x1000, 0x0)      = 4096 0
mmap(0x105F64000, 0x52000, 0x5, 0x12, 0x3, 0x0)      = 0x105F64000 0
mmap(0x105FB6000, 0xD000, 0x3, 0x12, 0x3, 0x52000)       = 0x105FB6000 0
mmap(0x105FC3000, 0x1C1C4, 0x1, 0x12, 0x3, 0x5F000)      = 0x105FC3000 0
close(0x3)       = 0 0
getattrlist("/Applications\0", 0x108AAD088, 0x7FFEEDEBFA70)      = 0 0
getattrlist("/Applications/MAMP\0", 0x108AAD088, 0x7FFEEDEBFA70)         = 0 0
getattrlist("/Applications/MAMP/Library\0", 0x108AAD088, 0x7FFEEDEBFA70)         = 0 0
getattrlist("/Applications/MAMP/Library/lib\0", 0x108AAD088, 0x7FFEEDEBFA70)         = 0 0
getattrlist("/Applications/MAMP/Library/lib/libMagickWand-6.Q16.2.dylib\0", 0x108AAD088, 0x7FFEEDEBFA70)         = 0 0
stat64("/Applications/MAMP/Library/lib/libMagickWand-6.Q16.2.dylib\0", 0x7FFEEDEC0330, 0x0)      = 0 0
open("/Applications/MAMP/Library/lib/libMagickWand-6.Q16.2.dylib\0", 0x0, 0x0)       = 3 0
pread(0x3, "\317\372\355\376\a\0", 0x1000, 0x0)      = 4096 0
mmap(0x105FE0000, 0x21F000, 0x5, 0x12, 0x3, 0x0)         = 0x105FE0000 0
mmap(0x1061FF000, 0x4000, 0x3, 0x12, 0x3, 0x21F000)      = 0x1061FF000 0
mmap(0x106203000, 0x1A92C, 0x1, 0x12, 0x3, 0x223000)         = 0x106203000 0
close(0x3)       = 0 0
getattrlist("/Applications\0", 0x108AAD088, 0x7FFEEDEBFA70)      = 0 0
getattrlist("/Applications/MAMP\0", 0x108AAD088, 0x7FFEEDEBFA70)         = 0 0
getattrlist("/Applications/MAMP/Library\0", 0x108AAD088, 0x7FFEEDEBFA70)         = 0 0
getattrlist("/Applications/MAMP/Library/lib\0", 0x108AAD088, 0x7FFEEDEBFA70)         = 0 0
getattrlist("/Applications/MAMP/Library/lib/libtiff.5.dylib\0", 0x108AAD088, 0x7FFEEDEBFA70)         = 0 0
stat64("/Applications/MAMP/Library/lib/libtiff.5.dylib\0", 0x7FFEEDEC0330, 0x0)      = 0 0
open("/Applications/MAMP/Library/lib/libtiff.5.dylib\0", 0x0, 0x0)       = 3 0
pread(0x3, "\317\372\355\376\a\0", 0x1000, 0x0)      = 4096 0
mmap(0x10621E000, 0x8C000, 0x5, 0x12, 0x3, 0x0)      = 0x10621E000 0
mmap(0x1062AA000, 0x4000, 0x3, 0x12, 0x3, 0x8C000)       = 0x1062AA000 0
mmap(0x1062AE000, 0xB3BC, 0x1, 0x12, 0x3, 0x90000)       = 0x1062AE000 0
close(0x3)       = 0 0
getattrlist("/Applications\0", 0x108AAD088, 0x7FFEEDEBFA70)      = 0 0
getattrlist("/Applications/MAMP\0", 0x108AAD088, 0x7FFEEDEBFA70)         = 0 0
getattrlist("/Applications/MAMP/Library\0", 0x108AAD088, 0x7FFEEDEBFA70)         = 0 0
getattrlist("/Applications/MAMP/Library/lib\0", 0x108AAD088, 0x7FFEEDEBFA70)         = 0 0
getattrlist("/Applications/MAMP/Library/lib/libMagickCore-6.Q16.2.dylib\0", 0x108AAD088, 0x7FFEEDEBFA70)         = 0 0
stat64("/Applications/MAMP/Library/lib/libMagickCore-6.Q16.2.dylib\0", 0x7FFEEDEC0330, 0x0)      = 0 0
open("/Applications/MAMP/Library/lib/libMagickCore-6.Q16.2.dylib\0", 0x0, 0x0)       = 3 0
pread(0x3, "\317\372\355\376\a\0", 0x1000, 0x0)      = 4096 0
mmap(0x1062BA000, 0x4A3000, 0x5, 0x12, 0x3, 0x0)         = 0x1062BA000 0
mmap(0x10675D000, 0xA5000, 0x3, 0x12, 0x3, 0x4A3000)         = 0x10675D000 0
mmap(0x106804000, 0x45928, 0x1, 0x12, 0x3, 0x548000)         = 0x106804000 0
madvise(0x106804000, 0x2000, 0x2)        = 0 0
close(0x3)       = 0 0
madvise(0x106804000, 0x2000, 0x5)        = 0 0
sysctl([CTL_HW, 3, 0, 0, 0, 0] (2), 0x7FFEEDEBEB7C, 0x7FFEEDEBEB70, 0x0, 0x0)        = 0 0
sysctl([CTL_HW, 3, 0, 0, 0, 0] (2), 0x7FFEEDEBEBDC, 0x7FFEEDEBEBD0, 0x0, 0x0)        = 0 0
getattrlist("/Applications\0", 0x108AAD088, 0x7FFEEDEBFD70)      = 0 0
getattrlist("/Applications/MAMP\0", 0x108AAD088, 0x7FFEEDEBFD70)         = 0 0
getattrlist("/Applications/MAMP/bin\0", 0x108AAD088, 0x7FFEEDEBFD70)         = 0 0
getattrlist("/Applications/MAMP/bin/php\0", 0x108AAD088, 0x7FFEEDEBFD70)         = 0 0
getattrlist("/Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php7.2.14\0", 0x108AAD088, 0x7FFEEDEBFD70)       = 0 0
getattrlist("/Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php7.2.14/lib\0", 0x108AAD088, 0x7FFEEDEBFD70)       = 0 0
getattrlist("/Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php7.2.14/lib/php\0", 0x108AAD088, 0x7FFEEDEBFD70)       = 0 0
getattrlist("/Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php7.2.14/lib/php/extensions\0", 0x108AAD088, 0x7FFEEDEBFD70)        = 0 0
getattrlist("/Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php7.2.14/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20170718\0", 0x108AAD088, 0x7FFEEDEBFD70)      = 0 0
getattrlist("/Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php7.2.14/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20170718/zmq.so\0", 0x108AAD088, 0x7FFEEDEBFD70)       = 0 0
stat64("/Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php7.2.14/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20170718/zmq.so\0", 0x7FFEEDEC0630, 0x0)        = 0 0
open("/Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php7.2.14/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20170718/zmq.so\0", 0x0, 0x0)         = 3 0
pread(0x3, "\317\372\355\376\a\0", 0x1000, 0x0)      = 4096 0
mmap(0x10684A000, 0xE000, 0x5, 0x12, 0x3, 0x0)       = 0x10684A000 0
mmap(0x106858000, 0x2000, 0x3, 0x12, 0x3, 0xE000)        = 0x106858000 0
mmap(0x10685A000, 0x8200, 0x1, 0x12, 0x3, 0x10000)       = 0x10685A000 0
close(0x3)       = 0 0
getattrlist("/usr\0", 0x108AAD088, 0x7FFEEDEBFB90)       = 0 0
getattrlist("/usr/local\0", 0x108AAD088, 0x7FFEEDEBFB90)         = 0 0
getattrlist("/usr/local/opt\0", 0x108AAD088, 0x7FFEEDEBFB90)         = 0 0
getattrlist("/usr/local/opt/zeromq\0", 0x108AAD088, 0x7FFEEDEBFB90)      = 0 0
readlink("/usr/local/opt/zeromq\0", 0x7FFEEDEBEF90, 0x400)       = 24 0
getattrlist("/usr/local/Cellar\0", 0x108AAD088, 0x7FFEEDEBFB90)      = 0 0
getattrlist("/usr/local/Cellar/zeromq\0", 0x108AAD088, 0x7FFEEDEBFB90)       = 0 0
getattrlist("/usr/local/Cellar/zeromq/4.3.1_1\0", 0x108AAD088, 0x7FFEEDEBFB90)       = 0 0
getattrlist("/usr/local/Cellar/zeromq/4.3.1_1/lib\0", 0x108AAD088, 0x7FFEEDEBFB90)       = 0 0
getattrlist("/usr/local/Cellar/zeromq/4.3.1_1/lib/libzmq.5.dylib\0", 0x108AAD088, 0x7FFEEDEBFB90)        = 0 0
stat64("/usr/local/opt/zeromq/lib/libzmq.5.dylib\0", 0x7FFEEDEC0450, 0x0)        = 0 0
open("/usr/local/opt/zeromq/lib/libzmq.5.dylib\0", 0x0, 0x0)         = 3 0
pread(0x3, "\317\372\355\376\a\0", 0x1000, 0x0)      = 4096 0
mmap(0x106863000, 0x5A000, 0x5, 0x12, 0x3, 0x0)      = 0x106863000 0
mmap(0x1068BD000, 0x7000, 0x3, 0x12, 0x3, 0x5A000)       = 0x1068BD000 0
mmap(0x1068C4000, 0x2DC2C, 0x1, 0x12, 0x3, 0x61000)      = 0x1068C4000 0
close(0x3)       = 0 0
open_nocancel("/Applications/MAMP/Library/OpenSSL/openssl.cnf\0", 0x0, 0x1B6)        = 3 0
fstat64(0x3, 0x7FFEEDEC0DA8, 0x0)        = 0 0
read_nocancel(0x3, "#\n# OpenSSL example configuration file.\n# This is mostly being used for generation of certificate requests.\n#\n\n# This definition stops the following lines choking if HOME isn't\n# defined.\nHOME\t\t\t= .\nRANDFILE\t\t= /Applications/MAMP/Library/OpenSSL/.rnd\n\n# Ex", 0x10000)       = 10859 0
read_nocancel(0x3, "id1}.5.6\n\n# Policies used by the TSA examples.\ntsa_policy1 = 1.2.3.4.1\ntsa_policy2 = 1.2.3.4.5.6\ntsa_policy3 = 1.2.3.4.5.7\n\n####################################################################\n[ ca ]\ndefault_ca\t= CA_default\t\t# The default ca section\n\n#####", 0x10000)        = 0 0
close_nocancel(0x3)      = 0 0
open_nocancel("/Applications/MAMP/Library/OpenSSL/openssl.cnf\0", 0x0, 0x1B6)        = 3 0
fstat64(0x3, 0x7FFEEDEC0DD8, 0x0)        = 0 0
read_nocancel(0x3, "#\n# OpenSSL example configuration file.\n# This is mostly being used for generation of certificate requests.\n#\n\n# This definition stops the following lines choking if HOME isn't\n# defined.\nHOME\t\t\t= .\nRANDFILE\t\t= /Applications/MAMP/Library/OpenSSL/.rnd\n\n# Ex", 0x10000)       = 10859 0
read_nocancel(0x3, "id1}.5.6\n\n# Policies used by the TSA examples.\ntsa_policy1 = 1.2.3.4.1\ntsa_policy2 = 1.2.3.4.5.6\ntsa_policy3 = 1.2.3.4.5.7\n\n####################################################################\n[ ca ]\ndefault_ca\t= CA_default\t\t# The default ca section\n\n#####", 0x10000)        = 0 0
close_nocancel(0x3)      = 0 0
socket(0x1E, 0x2, 0x0)       = 3 0
close(0x3)       = 0 0
madvise(0x1058CA000, 0x24000, 0x9)       = 0 0
sysctl([CTL_KERN, 8, 0, 0, 0, 0] (2), 0x7FFEEDEC0FFC, 0x7FFEEDEC0FF0, 0x0, 0x0)      = 0 0
open("/dev/urandom\0", 0x0, 0xFFFFFFFF9C000001)      = 3 0
fstat64(0x3, 0x7FFEEDEC0D88, 0x0)        = 0 0
fcntl(0x3, 0x1, 0x0)         = 0 0
fcntl(0x3, 0x2, 0x1)         = 0 0
read(0x3, "\205U\030\217\312\374\207Ua\257\372\022\255\261r\aical for a CA certificate. However since it will\n# prevent it being used as an test self-signed certificate it is best\n# left out by default.\n# keyUsage = cRLSign, keyCertSign\n\n# Some might want this also\n# nsCertType = sslCA, emailCA\n\n# In", 0x10)        = 16 0
stat64("/etc/cram-md5.pwd\0", 0x7FFEEDEC1030, 0x0)       = -1 Err#2
sysctl([CTL_KERN, 10, 0, 0, 0, 0] (2), 0x7FFEEDEC0C90, 0x7FFEEDEC0728, 0x0, 0x0)         = 0 0
setitimer(0x0, 0x7FFEEDEC03B0, 0x7FFEEDEC03D0)       = 0 0
setitimer(0x0, 0x7FFEEDEC0360, 0x7FFEEDEC0380)       = 0 0
open_nocancel("/etc/.mdns_debug\0", 0x0, 0x0)        = -1 Err#2
sysctl([CTL_NET, 17, 0, 0, 3, 0] (6), 0x0, 0x7FFEEDEBFA78, 0x0, 0x0)         = 0 0
sysctl([CTL_NET, 17, 0, 0, 3, 0] (6), 0x7FD337039A00, 0x7FFEEDEBFA78, 0x0, 0x0)      = 0 0
kqueue(0x0, 0x0, 0x0)        = 4 0
kevent(0x4, 0x7FFEEDEBFE20, 0x1)         = 0 0
socket(0x1, 0x1, 0x0)        = 5 0
setsockopt(0x5, 0xFFFF, 0x1022)      = 0 0
setsockopt(0x5, 0xFFFF, 0x1100)      = 0 0
connect_nocancel(0x5, 0x7FFEEDEBFA40, 0x6A)      = 0 0
sendto_nocancel(0x5, 0x7FD33902B990, 0x1C)       = 28 0
select_nocancel(0x6, 0x7FFEEDEBFA30, 0x0)        = 1 0
recvfrom_nocancel(0x5, 0x7FFEEDEBFA00, 0x4)      = 4 0
socketpair(0x1, 0x1, 0x0)        = 0 0
setsockopt(0x6, 0xFFFF, 0x1100)      = 0 0
sendto_nocancel(0x5, 0x7FD33902BA20, 0x33)       = 51 0
sendmsg_nocancel(0x5, 0x7FFEEDEBF950, 0x0)       = 1 0
close_nocancel(0x7)      = 0 0
select_nocancel(0x7, 0x7FFEEDEBF950, 0x0)        = 1 0
recvfrom_nocancel(0x6, 0x7FFEEDEBF920, 0x4)      = 4 0
close_nocancel(0x6)      = 0 0
socketpair(0x1, 0x1, 0x0)        = 0 0
setsockopt(0x6, 0xFFFF, 0x1100)      = 0 0
sendto_nocancel(0x5, 0x7FD33902BA20, 0x33)       = 51 0
sendmsg_nocancel(0x5, 0x7FFEEDEBF950, 0x0)       = 1 0
close_nocancel(0x7)      = 0 0
select_nocancel(0x7, 0x7FFEEDEBF950, 0x0)        = 1 0
recvfrom_nocancel(0x6, 0x7FFEEDEBF920, 0x4)      = 4 0
close_nocancel(0x6)      = 0 0
kevent(0x4, 0x7FFEEDEBFE20, 0x1)         = 0 0
Interactive shell <-------------- ALL THE OUTPUT ABOVE THIS LINE COMES WHILE WAITING SEVERAL SECONDS WITH imap.so ENABLED

php >
```

**EDIT:** Output with `imap.so` disabled:

```
$ sudo dtruss php -a
SYSCALL(args)        = return
Interactive shell <--- I SEE THE PROMPT RIGHTAWAY

php > madvise(0x1075D4000, 0x2000, 0x5)      = 0 0
madvise(0x107F45000, 0x2000, 0x5)        = 0 0
madvise(0x107309000, 0x7000, 0x5)        = 0 0
open("/dev/dtracehelper\0", 0x2, 0xFFFFFFFFE9D2BA60)         = 3 0
ioctl(0x3, 0x80086804, 0x7FFEE9D2B9C0)       = 0 0
close(0x3)       = 0 0
access("/AppleInternal/XBS/.isChrooted\0", 0x0, 0x0)         = -1 Err#2
thread_selfid(0x0, 0x0, 0x0)         = 814968 0
bsdthread_register(0x7FFF6EE05BEC, 0x7FFF6EE05BDC, 0x2000)       = 1073742047 0
mprotect(0x107622000, 0x1000, 0x0)       = 0 0
mprotect(0x107627000, 0x1000, 0x0)       = 0 0
mprotect(0x107690000, 0x1000, 0x0)       = 0 0
mprotect(0x107695000, 0x1000, 0x0)       = 0 0
mprotect(0x107427000, 0x88, 0x1)         = 0 0
mprotect(0x107429000, 0x1000, 0x1)       = 0 0
mprotect(0x107427000, 0x88, 0x3)         = 0 0
mprotect(0x107427000, 0x88, 0x1)         = 0 0
issetugid(0x0, 0x0, 0x0)         = 0 0
getpid(0x0, 0x0, 0x0)        = 84569 0
stat64("/AppleInternal/XBS/.isChrooted\0", 0x7FFEE9D29668, 0x0)      = -1 Err#2
stat64("/AppleInternal\0", 0x7FFEE9D29700, 0x0)      = -1 Err#2
csops(0x14A59, 0x7, 0x7FFEE9D291A0)      = -1 Err#22
sysctl([CTL_KERN, 14, 1, 84569, 0, 0] (4), 0x7FFEE9D292E8, 0x7FFEE9D292E0, 0x0, 0x0)         = 0 0
csops(0x14A59, 0x7, 0x7FFEE9D28A90)      = -1 Err#22
geteuid(0x0, 0x0, 0x0)       = 0 0
getuid(0x0, 0x0, 0x0)        = 0 0
sysctl([CTL_KERN, 14, 1, 84569, 0, 0] (4), 0x7FFEE9D27EB8, 0x7FFEE9D27E98, 0x0, 0x0)         = 0 0
gettid(0x7FFEE9D281D8, 0x7FFEE9D281DC, 0x0)      = -1 Err#3
geteuid(0x0, 0x0, 0x0)       = 0 0
getegid(0x0, 0x0, 0x0)       = 0 0
gettid(0x7FFEE9D281B8, 0x7FFEE9D281BC, 0x0)      = -1 Err#3
geteuid(0x0, 0x0, 0x0)       = 0 0
getegid(0x0, 0x0, 0x0)       = 0 0
...
ioctl(0x1, 0x4004667A, 0x7FFEE5E5A474)       = 0 0
stat64("/Users/antony/.terminfo\0", 0x7FFEE5E5A3F0, 0x0)         = -1 Err#2
stat64("/usr/share/terminfo\0", 0x7FFEE5E5A3F0, 0x0)         = 0 0
access("/usr/share/terminfo/78/xterm-256color\0", 0x4, 0x0)      = 0 0
open("/usr/share/terminfo/78/xterm-256color\0", 0x0, 0x0)        = 7 0
read(0x7, "\032\001%\0", 0x1001)         = 3322 0
close(0x7)       = 0 0
ioctl(0x1, 0x4004667A, 0x7FFEE5E5A474)       = 0 0
ioctl(0x1, 0x40487413, 0x7FFD49113348)       = 0 0
ioctl(0x1, 0x4004667A, 0x7FFEE5E5A424)       = 0 0
ioctl(0x1, 0x40087468, 0x7FFEE5E5A4A0)       = 0 0
ioctl(0x0, 0x40087468, 0x7FFEE5E5A948)       = 0 0
ioctl(0x0, 0x40087468, 0x7FFEE5E5A890)       = 0 0
ioctl(0x0, 0x80087467, 0x7FFEE5E5A890)       = 0 0
ioctl(0x0, 0x40487413, 0x7FFEE5E5A930)       = 0 0
stat64("/Users/antony/.inputrc\0", 0x7FFEE5E5A888, 0x0)      = 0 0
open("/Users/antony/.inputrc\0", 0x0, 0x1B6)         = 7 0
read(0x7, "set bell-style off\n\0", 0x13)        = 19 0
close(0x7)       = 0 0
ioctl(0x0, 0x40087468, 0x7FFEE5E5A8D0)       = 0 0
ioctl(0x0, 0x80087467, 0x7FFEE5E5A8D0)       = 0 0
ioctl(0x0, 0x40487413, 0x7FFEE5E5A9A0)       = 0 0
ioctl(0x0, 0x80487415, 0x7FFEE5E5A9A0)       = 0 0
sigprocmask(0x1, 0x10B730084, 0x10B730088)       = 0x0 0
sigaction(0x2, 0x7FFEE5E5A878, 0x7FFEE5E5A8C8)       = 0 0
sigaction(0xF, 0x7FFEE5E5A878, 0x7FFEE5E5A8C8)       = 0 0
sigaction(0x1, 0x7FFEE5E5A878, 0x7FFEE5E5A8C8)       = 0 0
sigaction(0x3, 0x7FFEE5E5A878, 0x7FFEE5E5A8C8)       = 0 0
sigaction(0xE, 0x7FFEE5E5A8C8, 0x7FFEE5E5A918)       = 0 0
sigaction(0x12, 0x7FFEE5E5A878, 0x7FFEE5E5A8C8)      = 0 0
sigaction(0x16, 0x7FFEE5E5A878, 0x7FFEE5E5A8C8)      = 0 0
sigaction(0x15, 0x7FFEE5E5A878, 0x7FFEE5E5A8C8)      = 0 0
sigprocmask(0x3, 0x10B730088, 0x0)       = 0x0 0
sigaction(0x1C, 0x7FFEE5E5A878, 0x7FFEE5E5A8C8)      = 0 0
write_nocancel(0x1, "php > \0", 0x6)         = 6 0
```

Comment: Can you check with `strace php -a` where it might stuck? Maybe even [edit] the question to include the relevant part of that output to your question, but the output might be quite big.

Comment: I do not have `strace` on OS X, is there an alternative command?

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31045575/how-to-trace-system-calls-of-a-program-in-mac-os-x

Comment: Are these the lines where it waits before showing the interactive shell text or the prompt? Please edit your question to include the strace/dtruss output where it waits/blocks for the mentioned time. If possible mark the specific line where it blocks. Maybe you need to post the whole output of strace/dtruss afterall.

Comment: OK, I will do that as soon as I lose the network connection again. It is really strange, but if I simply turn off Wi-Fi the command still works. It happens only when the connection is lost because of a network problem (which by the way happens frequently on the local network where I am connected)

Comment: @Progman Please check my edit, I posted the output of `dtruss` where `php -a` hangs

Comment: Please edit your question to include more output from the `dtruss` call before the wait/block. This way we see what php is trying to do or what he is working on.

Comment: Actually, `SYSCALL(args)        = return` is all I see during the block.. then the interactive shell prompt appears after several seconds. What could it be?

Comment: @Progman Please check my edit, I rerun the command and it generated further output.

Comment: Can you add the same output but with the imap.so extension disabled for comparison?

Comment: Sure, check my edit. I see the prompt rightaway in that case.