# Shared memory "Too many open files" but ipcs doesn't show many allocations

Tags: c++, c, macos, unix, shared-memory

I'm writing unit tests for code which creates shared memory.

I only have a couple of tests. I make 4 allocations of shared memory and then it fails on the fifth.

After calling `shmat()` `perror()` says `Too many open files`:

```
template <typename T> 
bool Attach(T** ptr, const key_type& key)
{
    // shmemId was 262151
    int32_t shmemId = shmget( key.key( ), ( size_t )0, 0644 );

    if (shmemId < 0)
    {
        perror("Error: ");
        return false;
    }

    *ptr = ( T * ) shmat(shmemId, 0, 0 );

    if ( ( int64_t ) * ptr < 0 )
    {
        // Problem is here. perror() says 'Too many open files'
        perror( "Error: ");
        return false;
    }

    return true;
}
```

However, when I check `ipcs -m -p` I only have a couple of shared memory allocations.

```
T     ID     KEY        MODE       OWNER    GROUP  CPID  LPID
Shared Memory:
m 262151 0x0000a028 --rw-r--r--                          3229      0
m 262152 0x0000a029 --rw-r--r--                          3229      0
```

In addition, when I check my OS shared memory limits `sysctl -A | grep shm` I get:

```
kern.sysv.shmall: 1024
kern.sysv.shmmax: 4194304
kern.sysv.shmmin: 1
kern.sysv.shmmni: 32
kern.sysv.shmseg: 8
security.mac.posixshm_enforce: 1
security.mac.sysvshm_enforce: 1
```

Are these variables large enough/are they the cause/what values should I have?

I'm sure I edited the file to increase them and restarted machine but perhaps it hasn't accepted (this is on Mac/OSX).

Comment: This code is definitely not C as it is tagged.

Comment: @273K `shmget()` and `shmat()` are C Unix API calls.

Comment: `if ( ( int64_t ) * ptr < 0 )` should be `if ( *ptr == reinterpret_cast<void*>(-1) )` if I read the documentation correctly.  Since it's C++, you could make `ptr` a `T*&` instead to not have to dereference `ptr` everywhere.

Comment: You tag the code used in the question, not the API.

Comment: @273K Do you have an answer to the problem?

Comment: @TedLyngmo The code isn't mine so I'm hesitant to change that. Do you think it's causing the problem or just it's not as good as it could be?

Comment: Answer to the problem: remove the tag C. As for an answer to the question, I have assumptions, but no [mcve] was posted for getting a correct answer.

Comment: @user997112 I don't think the cast will matter with regards to the number of open files. Changing to a `*&` instead of a `**` only simplifies the usage so that you can write `ptr` instead of `*ptr` inside the function. Please make a [mre] as suggested and it'll be easier to see if you leak resources.

Comment: “Too many open file” can not be checked with ipcs. Use lsof command (LiSt Open Files)

Answer (score 1):

Your problem may be elsewhere.

**Edit:** This may be a `shmmni` limit of macOS. See below.

---

When I run your [simplified] code on my system (linux), the `shmget` fails.

You didn't specify `IPC_CREAT` to the third argument. If another process has created the segment, this *may* be okay.

But, it doesn't/shouldn't like a size of 0. The [linux] man page states that it returns an error (`errno` set to EINVAL) if the size is less than `SHMMIN` (which is 1).

That is what happened on my system. So, I adjusted the code to use a size of 1.

This was done [as I mentioned] on linux.

macOS *may* allow a size of 0, even if that doesn't make practical sense. (e.g.) It may round it up to a page size.

---

For `shmat`, it returns `(void *) -1`.

But, some systems can have *valid* addresses that have the high bit set. (e.g.) 0xFFE0000000000000 is a valid address, but would fail your `if` test because casting that to `int64_t` will test negative.

Better to do:

```
if ((int64_t) *ptr == (int64_t) -1)
```

Or [possibly better]:

```
if ((void *) *ptr == (void *) -1)
```

Note that `errno` is *not* set/changed if the call succeeds.

To verify this, do: `errno = 0` *before* the `shmat` call. If `perror` says "Success", then the `shmat` is okay. And, your current test needs to be adjusted as above--I'd do that change regardless.

You could also do (e.g):

```
printf("ptr=%p\n",*ptr);
```

---

Normally, `errno` starts as 0.

Note that there *are* some differences between macOS and linux.

So, if `errno` is *ever* set to "too many open files", this can be because the *process* has too many open files (`EMFILE`).

It *might* be because the *system-wide* limit is reached (`ENFILE`) but that is "file table overflow".

Note that under *linux* `shmat` can *not* generate `EMFILE`. However, it appears that under macOS it *can*.

However, if the number of calls to `shmat` is limited [as you mention], the `shmat` should succeed.

The macOS man page is a little vague as to what the limit is based on. However, I checked the `FreeBSD` man page for `shmat` and that says it is limited by the `sysctl` parameter: `kern.ipc.shmseg`. Your `grep` *should* have caught that [if applicable].

It is possible some *other* syscall elsewhere in the code is opening too many files. And, *that* syscall is *not* checking the error return.

---

Again, I realize you're running `macOS`.

But, if available, you may want to try your program under linux. For example, it has much larger limits from the `sysctl`:

```
kernel.shm_next_id = -1
kernel.shm_rmid_forced = 0
kernel.shmall = 18446744073692774399
kernel.shmmax = 18446744073692774399
kernel.shmmni = 4096
vm.hugetlb_shm_group = 0
```

Note that `shmmni` is the *system-wide* maximum number of shared memory segments.

Note that for `macOS`, `shmmni` is 32 (vs. 4096 for linux)!?!?

That means that the *entire* system can only have 32 open shared memory segments for any/all processes???

That seems very low. You can probably *set* this to a larger number and see if that helps.

---

Linux has the `strace` program and you could use it to monitor the syscalls.

But, macOS has `dtruss`: [How to trace system calls of a program in Mac OS X?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31045575/how-to-trace-system-calls-of-a-program-in-mac-os-x)

Comment: *Better to do: `if ((int64_t) *ptr == (int64_t) -1)`*? The [POSIX documentation for `shmat()`](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799.2018edition/functions/shmat.html) says the return value is `(void *)-1` on failure, so the comparison should be `if ((void *) *ptr == (void *) -1)`