# macOS ktrace "-t c" system call tracing available on newer macOS?

Tags: macos, system-calls, trace, macos-monterey

Anyone know if there's a way to trace only system calls via `ktrace` in macOS 12+? (Obviously this is with SIP disabled.)

In the past one could trace system calls via:

```
sudo ktrace trace -s -S -t c -c ./some_binary
```

Now the `-t` is simply

> `Print times as Mach absolute timestamps, instead of the default local wall clock time.`

Answer (score 1):

The replacement for `-t trstr` seems to be `-f filter-desc`. The new filters are more flexible but arguably a bit fiddlier to use. Here's what the [manpage](https://keith.github.io/xcode-man-pages/ktrace.1.html#trace) has to say:

> `-f filter-desc`
>
> Apply a filter description to the trace session, controlling which
> events are traced.

> FILTER DESCRIPTIONS
>
> A filter description is a comma-separated list of class and subclass
> specifiers that indicate which events should be traced.  A class
> specifier starts with `C` and contains a single byte, specified in
> either decimal or hex.  A subclass specifier starts with `S` and takes
> two bytes.  The high byte is the class and the low byte is the
> subclass of that class.
>
> For example, this filter description would enable classes 1 and 37 and
> the subclasses 33 and 35 of class 5: `C1,C0x25,S0x0521,S0x0523`.

The possible values you can filter on are defined in [bsd/sys/kdebug.h](https://github.com/apple-oss-distributions/xnu/blob/aca3bea/bsd/sys/kdebug.h#L99) under `Class and subclass definitions`.

So if you're interested in BSD syscalls, that's `-f C4` (class 4 = `DBG_BSD`). Mach syscalls (aka traps) would be `-f S0x010c` (class 1 = `DBG_MACH`, subclass `0c` = `DBG_MACH_EXCP_SC`).

So to show BSD syscalls and Mach traps:

```bash
sudo ktrace trace -Ss -f C4,S0x010c -c ./some_binary
```

Depending on what you're after, you might also want `C2,C3` (`DBG_NETWORK` and `DBG_FSYSTEM`).